# Bash script behaves unexpected / Strange

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi2

First I want to apologize for being an absolute noob at programming, writing scripts, etc.
I'm running a FreeNAS Server and a Raspberry Pi which I'd like to include a sh-Script which should check if 8 clients (IP addresses) are online. If yes they should stop but if all IP's are offline, it should perform another task / script.

Here's my problem: On the internet (src: https://www.tech-blogger.net/freenas-automatisch-bei-nicht-benutzung-abschalten/) I found a script which checks specific IP's and if they're offline it should shutdown automatically. When I ping those addresses I get 100% package lost which indicates that they are offline. But the script echos me that at least one client is offline. Because I'm not THAT dumb I assume that it has something to do with my code. Does anyone know what goes wrong with my Script?:

```
HOST1=192.168.1.32
HOST2=192.168.1.33
HOST3=192.168.1.34
HOST4=192.168.1.35
HOST5=192.168.1.36

_exit () {
case $1 in
1) echo „No Shutdown – At least one PC is online“ ;;
2) echo „No PC is online – Shutdown“ ; shutdown -p now ;;
esac
exit $1;
}

#Check if IPs are online
if [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST1 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST2 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST3 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST4 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST5 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] ; then _exit 1;

#All Clients are offline, shutdown
else
_exit 2
fi
fi
```

Comment: `if [ $(cmd | grep -c ...) -eq 0 ]` is an anti-pattern.  Use `if ! cmd | grep -q ...` instead

Comment: But you shouldn't be using `grep` at all here.  `ping` will return 0 if it receives a response, non-zero otherwise, so you can just do `if ( ping -c 1 -t 1 $HOST1 || ping -c 1 -t 1 $HOST2 || ... ) > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then` to see if any host responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100 % sure if I get your Problem right. But I think you should try to replace || with && in your if statement.

|| = or
&& = and

Thus it will only go into the shutdown parts, when all Clients are off.

## edit:

```
ping -c 1 -i 1 192.168.1.36
PING 192.168.1.36 (192.168.1.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 62.155.241.85 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.1.36 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

It's 100% packet loss **not** 100.0%. Thus you check for something that does not occur.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST1=192.168.1.32
HOST2=192.168.1.33
HOST3=192.168.1.34
HOST4=192.168.1.35
HOST5=192.168.1.36

_exit () {
case $1 in
1) echo „No Shutdown – At least one PC is online“ ;;
2) echo „No PC is online – Shutdown“ ;; # shutdown -p now ;;
esac
exit $1;
}

#Check if IPs are online
if [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST1 | grep -wc 100%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST2 | grep -wc 100%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST3 | grep -wc 100%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST4 | grep -wc 100%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST5 | grep -wc 100%` -eq 0 ] ; then _exit 1;

#All Clients are offline, shutdown
else                                                                                                                                                                                           
_exit 2
fi
```

This works as expected ( on my machine ). :-)

Comment: Yes this worked fine. 
Thank you very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

As William Pursell said in a comment, when `ping` doesn't reach the requested IP, it returns a non-zero exit code indicating failure. The `if` statement in shells like Bash can use that exit code directly without having to use bracketed conditional expressions.

I would recommend a loop instead of a long conditional. This will be easier to read and maintain and scales more readily if the number of hosts change.

```bash
# create an array of IPs
host_ips=(
    192.168.1.32
    192.168.1.33
    192.168.1.34
    192.168.1.35
    192.168.1.36
)

for ip in "${host_ips[@]}"
do
    if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$ip"
    then
        _exit 1
        # no need to break since _exit doesn't return
    fi
done
# if we made it this far, none are online
_exit 2
```

Comment: I tried this but my Raspberry tells me there is a syntax error because of the ( in the second line.

Comment: @AlphaInc.: You need to make sure you're using Bash and not sh since the former supports arrays and the latter usually doesn't. `#!/bin/bash` should be the first line in your script.